# Building an SQL query based on checkboxes

Tags: php, sql, checkbox, where-clause

Let's say I have a form that has 30 checkboxes that correspond to music genres (it submits to a PHP form handler).

I have an artists table that has a genre field. What are the best practices on building a query that would behave along the lines of:

Select name FROM artists WHERE genreId = 1 OR genreId = 2 OR . . . etc etc. Where the genreId's are chosen from checkboxes.

I know I can dynamically build my WHERE clause in PHP, but I'm in the habit of using prepared statements and stored procedures. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would likely want to use `IN()` in your where clause like this:

```
WHERE genreId IN (1,2,3)
```

Unfortunately, there really isn't a good solution to use this in a parameterized way. You just have to go old-school:

```
$query = 'SELECT ... WHERE genreId IN (' . implode(',', $genreId_array) . ')';
```

I suppose though you could do something like this to build a parametrized approach:

```
$query = 'SELECT ... WHERE genreId IN (';
$array_length = count($genreId_array);
for ($i = 0; $i < $array_length; $i++) {
    $query .= '?,';
}
$query = rtrim(',',$query) . ')';
```

Comment: Make sure you acknowledge that the user might submit the form without selecting any checkboxes.

Comment: @Galway Certainly that validation should be done before you even get to the point of trying to form a query.

Comment: @MikeBrant Alright. Thanks gents. It's too bad there isn't much in terms of best practices. Never hurts to ask.