# Query building depending checkboxes selection

Tags: php, sql

I want to build a query form my database depending my checkboxes list.

## My checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="searchName" checked> Name
<input type="checkbox" id="searchAddress"> Address
<input type="checkbox" id="searchCompany"> Company
<input type="checkbox" id="searchComments"> Comments
```

## My PHP:

```
$subQuery='';
if($_POST['searchName']=='true')     { $subQuery .= " AND KDX_Name LIKE :KDX_SearchTerm"; }
if($_POST['searchAddress']=='true')  { $subQuery .= " OR KDX_PostalAddress LIKE :KDX_SearchTerm"; }
if($_POST['searchCompany']=='true')  { $subQuery .= " OR KDX_Company LIKE :KDX_SearchTerm"; }
if($_POST['searchComments']=='true') { $subQuery .= " OR KDX_Comments LIKE :KDX_SearchTerm"; }
```

## My problem:

If the first checkbox is not checked, my query is not working cause it works with `OR` whereas it must start with `AND`.

Could you please help ?

Thanks.

Comment: or [Dynamically Creating mysql select Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22986065/dynamically-creating-mysql-select-query)

Comment: This is not complete duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459150/building-an-sql-query-based-on-checkboxes It's a bit different :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many mistakes in your code in HTML and in PHP ...
I'll not mention everything here, but this is how I would do this.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="searchName" checked="checked" />Name
<input type="checkbox" name="searchAddress" />Address
<input type="checkbox" name="searchCompany" />Company
<input type="checkbox" name="searchComments" />Comments

<?php
$fields = array(
    'searchName'    => 'KDX_Name',
    'searchAddress' => 'KDX_PostalAddress',
    'searchCompany' => 'KDX_Company',
    'searchComments'=> 'KDX_Comments',
);

$cond = array();
foreach ($fields as $form_field => $db_field) {
    if (isset($_POST[$form_field])) {
        $cond[] = "$db_field LIKE '%'" . mysql_escape($_POST[$form_field]) . "%'";
    }
}

$subQuery = implode(' OR ', $cond);
?>
```

More important are these things:

- correct HTML form (not id, but name),
- easy to extend PHP (use array for field names),
- don't check for $_POST[foo]=='true' which is absolutely wrong,
- add conditions in array and at the end use implode to easily concatenate everything together,
- escape user input variables to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Going back from PDO to the `mysql_*` functions seems like a very bad idea.

Comment: Yeah, OK, you can use PDO - that doesn't matter so much in this case. See my edit above.